# Rewrite query string to path params

Tags: nginx

I have the following configuration of nginx that hosts my image service:

```
    upstream thumbor {
        server localhost:8888;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  my.imageserver.com;
        client_max_body_size 10M;
        rewrite_log on;
        location ~ /images { 
            if ($arg_width="10"){
                rewrite ^/images(/.*)$ /unsafe/$1 last;
            }
            rewrite ^/images(/.*)$ /unsafe/$1 last;
        }
        location ~ /unsafe {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

            proxy_pass http://thumbor;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
            return 204;
            access_log     off;
            log_not_found  off;
        }
    }
```

I am trying to rewrite the following urls:

**from**

my.imageserver.com/images/Jenesis/EmbeddedImage/image/jpeg/jpeg/9f5d124d-068d-43a4-92c0-1c044584c54a.jpeg

**to**

my.imageserver.com/unsafe/Jenesis/EmbeddedImage/image/jpeg/jpeg/9f5d124d-068d-43a4-92c0-1c044584c54a.jpeg

which is quite easy, the problem begins when I want to allow query string that should go to the path of the url like so:

**from**

my.imageserver.com/images/Jenesis/EmbeddedImage/image/jpeg/jpeg/9f5d124d-068d-43a4-92c0-1c044584c54a.jpeg?width=150&height=200&mode=smart

**to**

/my.imageserver.com/unsafe/150x200/smart/Jenesis/EmbeddedImage/image/jpeg/jpeg/9f5d124d-068d-43a4-92c0-1c044584c54a.jpeg

Also it will be better if the order of the query strings won't matter.

I tried using:
$arg_width but it didn't seem to work.

Using nginx 1.6.1 on ubuntu.

Help would be much much appreciated.

Comment: What the reason? Usually people wants quite opposite

Comment: It's part of our image service and we prefer having clients add query params to the URL instead of in the middle of the path

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way :

```
location ~ /images {
    rewrite '^/images/(.*)$' '/unsafe/${arg_width}x${arg_height}/${arg_mode}/$1?' last;
}
```

Nginx rewrite log :

`"^/images/(.*)$" matches "/images/Jenesis/EmbeddedImage/image/jpeg/jpeg/9f5d124d-068d-43a4-92c0-1c044584c54a.jpeg", request: "GET /images/Jenesis/EmbeddedImage/image/jpeg/jpeg/9f5d124d-068d-43a4-92c0-1c044584c54a.jpeg?width=150&height=200&mode=smart HTTP/1.1"`

`rewritten data: "/unsafe/150x200/smart/Jenesis/EmbeddedImage/image/jpeg/jpeg/9f5d124d-068d-43a4-92c0-1c044584c54a.jpeg", args: "", request: "GET /images/Jenesis/EmbeddedImage/image/jpeg/jpeg/9f5d124d-068d-43a4-92c0-1c044584c54a.jpeg?width=150&height=200&mode=smart HTTP/1.1"`

But it's better to do the opposite as you can have a cleaner way to validate arguments in one line of nginx configuration.